# Delete two redundant symbols from each element of a string array

Tags: javascript, regex

I think this question should be an easy one. I use a regex expression which, actually is:

```
 str_pow = str_input.match(/(?:x)[^][+-]?\d{1,4}\s/g);
```

The problem lays in that I need only numbers, though they're still of string type(don't think about this), but not this part x^. Currently the how str_pow looks like is this

[image]

This means two things: I've to either edit my regex mask, or to find a way to cut the first two "x^" characters of for each element i of the array. Can you help me to do this, because I tried to slice but it was an unsuccessful experiment.

Comment: What do you want to match actually?

Comment: just the numbers after `^x`  but  I need the ^x part in order to pick the proper values from the string

Comment: `str_pow` appear to be array , not string ? What is expected result ? array of digits ?

Comment: I think it's the console which says it's an array. Indeed, the type of this array is string => it is a string array filled with `x^some_numbers_here` -elements and I need to cut those `x^` in order to parse the `some_numbers_here` part later and convert it into an integer for further calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop the array:

```
var a = ["x^5 ", "x^4 ", "x^2 ", "x^1 "];

for(var i = 0; i< a.length; i++) {
    a[i] = parseInt(a[i].substring(2, a[i].length).trim(), 10);
}
console.log(a);
```

Comment: what this `,10` stands for?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: aha, ok, it is the numerical system... I'm testing right now 1 mom

Comment: Thank you very much, it works completely fine. Thanks, again. :)